# How to set Secure Transfer Required for a Storage Account?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-management-api, azure-management

How to set Secure Transfer Required (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/secure-transfer-required-is-available-in-azure-storage-account/) for Azure Storage Accounts on using Azure Management Libraries for .NET (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-management-libraries-for-net-generally-available-now/) with Fluent APIs?

I guess full support is not yet available 2017-10-14 but what would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not exactly sure what issue you're running into, or what you're referring to with "2017-10-14" (that's not an API version/date), but you can set a storage account to use secure-only (ssl) transfer via several methods: Portal, PowerShell, CLI, and one of the numerous language sdk's wrapping the management API (.net, python, ruby, node).

Note: You can only use secure-only transfer with storage accounts created via Resource Manager. It's not supported with "classic" storage accounts.